# What is the structural (positive or negative) answer for "Is this a courgette"?

Tags: answers, demonstrative

I know that when answering on an question with a structure of interrogative structure, then there is a short structural answer which based on the tense or the lexical verb that the questioner asked. For example:

> **Questioner**: Is **it** tall? Does it go?
>
> **Short structural answers**: Yes, it is. / No, it is not. / Yes, it does. / No, it does not.

Now my question is on a case where I use [demonstratives](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/demonstrative) instead of [pronouns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pronoun), then should I use demonstrative in the short structural answer as well?

For example:

> "Is **this** a courgette"?

The choices are as the follow:

> Yes, **this** is. / No **this** is not. /  Yes, **it** is. / No. **it** is not.

Comment: Yes to all of the above.  There's no real semantic difference between *"Yes, this is"* and *"Yes, it is"*.  I can't even say it's a matter of *style* --  if anything it's just about mirroring the subject of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible, and quite natural, to use a pronoun in response to a question using a demonstrative:

> Q: Is **this** a courgette?
>
> A1: Yes, **it** is.
>
> A2: No, **it** isn't.  ["No, it's not" is also acceptable; "No it is not," is as well, but most people will use one of the contracted forms in casual speech.]
>
> A3: No, **it's** a cucumber.  ["No" can also be used with a positively-worded correction to the question.]

It is also possible to use a demonstrative, however in many cases that the answer will involve the "opposite" demonstrative, especially with a small object like a courgette.  That is, the questioner uses **this** to identify the courgette he is holding or that is right in front of him, which means the responder will probably use **that** since the courgette is not their possession (it's still being held by the questioner).

> Q: Is **this** a courgette?
>
> A1: Yes, **that** is.
>
> A2: No, **that** isn't.  ["No, that's not" is also acceptable.]
>
> A3: No, **that's** a cucumber.

You can imagine situations where the question using **this** is answered with an answer also using **this**, but in most cases that means some action has happened in between that moves the courgette from the questioner's possession/vicinity to the responder's possession/vicinity.

> Q: Is **this** a courgette?
>
> *[Q hands the vegetable to A, who examines it closely.]*
>
> A: Yes, **this** is a courgette.

Here, both Q and A are using **this**, but not for consistency's sake.  On the contrary, it demonstrates that the courgette began our little story in Q's possession, but moved to A's possession at the end.

If you are dealing with a much larger object, then it's more likely that both Q and A could plausibly use **this** for the same object without some physical transfer.  For example, if both  people are passengers on an airplane:

> Q: Is **this** a Boeing 787?
>
> A: No, **this** is an Airbus A350.

Here, both Q and A have the same "closeness" to the airplane, so it makes sense for both of them to use **this**.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you can save me another post and tell me if it's possible to use the model of "short answer" for "there is" and "there are". For example, "Are there cucumbers in the refrigerator?" -the answer 'Yes, there are." works?

Comment: Yes, that is correct and very idiomatic. The negative response would be, "No, there aren't [any]." You could also say, "Yes, there is one," if there is only one cucumber left.